How to recursively include template from another project that has nested templates
So I have the following Azure DevOps pipeline that includes templates from a repository in another project. Including that isn't the problem though.
The issue is that the template included has nested templates that it also includes. When it includes them in this pipeline, it looks for them in the local repo, rather than recursively doing it so that it looks for those templates in that other project. I hope that makes sense.
Is there a way to do this?
trigger:
- none
 
pr: none
 
parameters:
- name: test
  displayName: Test
  type: string
  default: test
 
 
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: more-templates
      type: git
      name: project2/repo2
      ref: dev-r1
 
variables:
- template: /variables/var.yaml@more-templates
 
name: Test-pipeline
 
pool: 
  name: $(AGENT_POOL)
 
stages:
 
- template: /pipelines/test/stage.yaml@more-templates
  parameters:
    test: testing

** Update **
I wanted to give a bit more clarity on what I'm trying to do, so hopefully this image helps.
Pipeline1 includes a template from a different repo in a different project. Template1 gets included with no problem - the issue is that Template1 also has other templates that it is including, after Template1 gets included by Pipeline1, it looks for Template2 (and the others) in Repo1, instead of Repo2.


Agree with Rui's answer. According to the document, When you refer to the core repo, use @ and the name you gave it in resources. You can check if you have use @self in your nested template. You can remove the @self from the nested template or change it to @more-templates


The issue is that the template included has nested templates that it also includes. When it includes them in this pipeline, it looks for them in the local repo, rather than recursively doing it so that it looks for those templates in that other project

I suspect you're using @self somewhere in the other project templates. For example:
# /variables/var.yaml@more-templates

variables:
  - template: common-variables.yaml@self

  # other variables here

That could explain your issue, given that @self is a reference to the repository where /variables/var.yaml was included from.
The fix in that case would be to simply remove the @self reference:
# /variables/var.yaml@more-templates

variables:
  - template: common-variables.yaml

  # other variables here


I just checked and it's not using @self after any of the templates.

@xil3  is it using any other template references such as @my-other-templates?

Not using any reference

@xil3 that's weird. When you say "nested templates" do you mean templates in the same repository? What I'm trying to understand is how many repositories are you referencing, directly or indirectly.

I added more information to the question, with a diagram. Hopefully that sheds some light on my issue.

Any ideas? Been stumped on this for awhile.

Hi @xil3, could you please share the content structure of Template 1, Template 2 and Template 3 to reproduce this issue? You can delete your other tasks and just need to share a minimal reproducible sample.

I tested to include Template 1 from Repo2 in the pipeline1, then Template 2 is included in Template 1, and Template 3 is included in Template 2. I found it works in my pipeline. It will not look for the template from the self-repo if I didn't use @self to reference a template.

@xil3 there is one and only one repository in project 2, right?

No, both projects have lots of repositories - I just put 1 in each to illustrate the issue. I'll put together some examples of what the templates look like

Sorry @xil3 I didn't explain myself properly. I'm trying to understand if Repo 2 is referencing templates from a different repository.

Ah I see what you mean - no it's not, all the templates are in Repo 2.

I'm running out of ideas :-) It might help to see how you're referencing the sub-templates. Also, do you use checkout tasks or anything like that?

I think I found the issue, which is what you pointed out before. A few of the templates which were nested like 4-5 levels deep were using @self. This is a very large library of templates, so I missed it.

Ctrl+Shift+F (find all references) is one of my favourite shortcuts in VS Code :-)

Yes, definitely some lessons learned here. Thank you again.
